# Basic questions about OpenCV with Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I am playing around with Python and OpenCV (`import cv2`) on Ubuntu. I have some basic questions.

- Am I right to assume that OpenCV is the de facto standard for open-source computer vision, esp. face recognition and OpenCV is a "mature" library?
- Is it correct that the library works "out of the box" and the algorithms are already sufficiently trained?
- Is further training helpful and how can I train the algorithms myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Tl;DR OpenCV is a mature library for computer vision, although it's not specific to face recognition, it does come with algorithms that you can train to fit your needs. You may also use OpenCV to build your own face recognition algorithms.***

Yes it is a mature library for computer vision that has and still undergoing development for several years (initial release ~2000) with notorious maintainers like Intel and Willow Garage.

However it is a library for computer vision, as in not specific to facial recognition. OpenCV prevents you from reinventing the wheel so e.g. you don't have to implement the low-level processing yourself if you don't have to

That said, OpenCV does come with a `contrib` package that's got a few algorithms for [facial recognition](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d60/tutorial_face_main.html#gsc.tab=0), like [FaceRecognizer](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html)

The bundled algorithms can give good results out of the box, but you'll have to train them to fit your needs, e.g. with [`FaceRecognizer.train()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html#facerecognizer-train)